# How Can I iterate this map in reverse direction

Tags: java

This is my map with iterators to remove some data based on some conditions, now I want to run the same map in reverse direction and conditions accordingly.

But I couldn't find any `ListIterator` to go back easily.

How Can I go about this ?

Also the `Map` implementation I am using is a `TreeMap`

```
for(int i=countIteration;i<(countIteration+2);i++)
{
    Iterator it = imageFilexxSm.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        if(pairs.getKey().equals(data1.get(i).replace(".png", ".mp3")))  
        {
            it.remove();
        }
    }

    Iterator itr = imageFilexxS.entrySet().iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairsx = (Map.Entry)itr.next();
        if(pairsx.getKey().equals(data1.get(i)))     
        {
            System.out.println("entry deleted."+pairsx.getKey());
            itr.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`TreeMap` has a [`descendingMap` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#descendingMap%28%29) (note that it returns a view on the original map, it does not copy it):

```
//iterate over the entry set in reverse order
for (Map.Entry<X,Y> e : map.descendingMap().entrySet()) {
    X key = e.getKey();
    Y value = e.getValue();
}
```

Comment: `NavigableMap` is such a great interface :)

Comment: What's the time complexity (big O) of map.descendingMap()? Can we use this to iterate over the k greatest keys in O(k) time?

Comment: `map.descendingMap()` is O(1), it just returns a wrapper around the original `TreeMap`.

Comment: The Java 21 [`reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html#reversed()) method on `TreeMap` is equivalent to `descendingMap`; it's the method from the new `SequencedMap` interface with the same behavior as the legacy method `descendingMap` on `NavigableMap`.